# User Input resulting in output of incorrect If-Statement branch

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

For my program I am attempting to create a public static String method that takes an integer and a string and outputs a string based on what month is inputted by the user. When I compile my code and run the program, the console correctly outputs the correct string message when I input any month except "February". But when I input "February" for month_name the program incorrectly proceeds with the first if condition and outputs the default condition of the switch embedded within the first if condition. Shouldn't it proceed to the else condition because month_name DOES equal "February"?

I've gone over the code and wondered if it was because I didn't properly close the methods with brackets or I didn't put a semi-colon at the end of any of the statements but that wasn't the case. I checked to make sure everything was spelled correctly. I checked to make sure that I was inputting in the correct string values but I am having trouble figuring out what is going on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class DaysInMonth { 

   public static String daysInaMonth (int year_number, String month_name) {
      if(month_name != "February") {
         switch(month_name) {
            case "January":
            case "March":
            case "May":
            case "July":
            case "August":
            case "October":
            case "December":
              return "There are 31 days in " + month_name + " " + year_number;
            case "April":
            case "June":
            case "September":
            case "November":
                return "There are 30 days in " + month_name + " " + year_number;
            default:
                return "Please input month";
         }  
      }

      else {
         if(year_number % 4 == 0) {
            return "There are 29 days in February " + year_number;
         }
         else {
            return "There are 28 days in February " + year_number;
         }

      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
   String month = " ";
   int year = 0;

   year = scnr.nextInt();

   month = scnr.next();

   System.out.print(daysInaMonth(year, month));


   }


}
```

Comment: Use `.equals()` for string comparisons in Java, instead of `==` or `!=`

Comment: Also, your leap year calculation is missing the [special handling for years divisible by 100 or 400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java, you cannot compare strings using logical operators (==, !=, etc.).  Doing this compares the string references (not values).

Do this instead...

```
if (!month_name.equals("February")) {

}
```